# Download Objects from S3 Bucket using c# always times out

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I've following test Lambda function which is meant to download a file of 1Kb from S3. Wondering why function always times out:

**Code:**

```
public void  FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
{
    TransferUtilityDownloadRequest downloadRequest = new TransferUtilityDownloadRequest();
    downloadRequest.BucketName = "s3bucket";
    downloadRequest.FilePath = @"/mnt/lambdaefs";
    downloadRequest.Key = "A/B/hello.txt";
    

    TransferUtility transfer = new TransferUtility("accessKey", "secretKey", Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
    transfer.Download(downloadRequest);

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"/mnt/lambdaefs");
    var files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
    foreach (var item in files)
        LambdaLogger.Log(item.FullName);
}
```

**Error:**

```
{"errorMessage":"2021-01-19T07:07:45.377Z ea960e83-d1b0-45db-9ffb-6b0895351c88 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"}
```

Comment: To find root cause, I would suggest to enable verbose logging; Possible issues can be;

1) Lambda timeout is set to less duration, but the logic needs more Timeout duration. To start with keep it maximum, then reduce it as per your analysis based on successful execution duration from the logs. 

2) Is connection to desired AWS EFS successful? check Lambda's VPC configuration (i.e. VPC id, Subnets and Security group) are those correct or not

Comment: @amitd Yes, connection to AWS EFS working fine.

Comment: @amitd moreover, if Lambda is taking more than 30 sec to download a 1KB file within VPC, then just imagine the performance, one should never use it in that case. I've already tried increasing the Timeout, it has no effect. File never gets downloaded, and function times out.